# Automatically rebuild referenced Class Libraries (DLLs) in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, build, compilation, rebuild

I have an executable project A, which references to a Class Library project B. However, when I build A, it does not automatically rebuild B. The only way to get B rebuilt and used by A is to rebuild B then build A.

Is there a way I can get B to be rebuilt automatically and then used by A when I build A?

Comment: If you want to rebuild project B when it need not be built, then I think you need to do a 'Rebuild solution'.

Comment: I don't think he means "rebuild" in the Visual Studio sense.  I think he just means "build".

Comment: @Canoehead: Rebuild solution does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check B in your solution configuration.

Comment: Specifically, that dropdown that says "Debug / Release", choose "Configuration Manager".

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify it was: `Right click on Solution > Properties > Configuration > Check "Build" next to project`